# Find local extrema, intervals where the function is increasing, and intervals where the function is decreasing. $g(x)=2x+\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

So I have taken the derivative which would be $$g'(x)= 2+(-\sin(x)).$$
Then I tried setting it equal to zero and got as far as  $$\sin(x)=2$$
When I put $\sin^{-1}(2)$ into my calculator it just said `error:domain error`.
Where do I go from here?

Comment: Well, that just means that the derivative is never zero; what can you conclude about the function? Also, you shouldn't need a calculator to compute this: The range of the sine function is $[-1, 1]$, which does not contain $2$. This should also tell you what the sign of the derivative is.

Comment: So what about drawing a graph of $g'(x)$? And what can you tell about its sign?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't take the arcsine of any value greater than $1$ or less than $-1$. This simply means there are no extrema. Plug in any $x$ value to $g'$ and if it's positive, $g$ is continually increasing. If negative, $g$ is continually decreasing.